# Can javascriptcore framework on iOS access network?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

I am trying to use a 3rd party javascript library from swift using the javascriptcore framework.  The library provides an API to a network service, but it won't connect.  Can I expect this to work?  Or, will javascriptcore lack platform-specific interfaces to use network on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, javascriptcore on iOS does not have any built-in support for network access, so this will not work unless I provide native methods for network access.